# Setting the right overflow in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap `wrapper` class. I am getting a scrollbar on y-axis by setting `overflow-y:scroll`. I have `dropdown-menu-right` in the wrapper class with a higher z-index. If I set `overflow-x:hidden`, the `dropdown-menu-right` is shown partially inside the div. If I set `overflow-x:scroll` or `overflow-x:visible`, a scrollbar-x gets created inside the `wrapper` class.I want a scrollbar on the y-axis and I don't want the `dropdown-menu-right` to be contained on the x-axis.

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: -320px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.dropdown-menu-right {
  right: -272px;
  left: auto;
  top: -200px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I could answer you more clearly if you included some code. But the clue is that (I suppose) you are trying to show a block which is bigger than the one containing it. To solve it, just change to `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`